# How to search a string in an Oracle Apex page having multiple reports?

Tags: oracle-apex

Suppose there are 3 Reports in an Oracle Apex page and I want to search all the columns of all the reports to get the matched string that the user will search. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own search item; let's call it `P1_SEARCH`. Modify all reports' queries and add condition into their `WHERE` clauses, e.g.

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
  -- add this:
  and (   (column_1 = :P1_SEARCH or 
           column_2 = :P1_SEARCH or
           ...
          )
      or :P1_SEARCH is null
     )
```

Columns you'd use should *make sense* (i.e. there's no use in searching `DATE` datatype columns for "Ashi", is there?).

---

Looking at what you should do (using that suggestion, of course), I'd say that it is simpler to use Apex engine and search 3 times, report-by-report.